# Segoe UI Symbols

Tags: user-interface, fonts

Okay, I'm not really sure this is actually a 'programming question', butit's closely related to programming.
Now, I am coding a fairly simple game in a 3D Lua Engine, which has quite a lot of GUI tools and options. The problem is, you can't set your own font on the GUIs and I want to use the symbols from Segoe UI Symbol.

Is it possible to get these icons from Segoe UI as raw images (png?jpg? anything..); somehow? Even if the quality reduces or something, the icons will be in very small boxes, so it won't matter.

Comment: Have you tried making strings with the desired codepoints and using a font rendering engine and output it to some image buffer, then importing the generated images?

Comment: err? I rarely read a sentence, in which I know every single word, but can't understand it.. Would you explain how exacly should I do this, please? At the same time, I'll do some googling..

Comment: I guess I can draw text on a transparent BufferedImage in Java, then save it and import it in the Lua Engine..

Comment: [SyncFusion's MetroStudio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) has the option to export text to various formats.

Comment: Oh, god, thank you! I looked into moshbear's solution, which wasn't actually that bad, but manually doing that work is tiring and obviously uneeded. Thanks again.